# How do I build link with specific part of params hash from previous request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, parameters, link-to

While I wouldn't normally create a page like this, please know this is a current constraint I can't change.

The page has a checkbox form as well as a table with links for THs that sort the table. I need to construct the TH link in a way that it retains the checkbox items already checked.

Checkbox constructed in View with Haml as:

```
= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do
Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", "1", (@ratingsarray.include?(rating) ? true : false)
  = hidden_field_tag 'sort', @sort
  = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

Then for the table it has this for the TH

```
%th{:class => @classrelease_date}  
  %a#release_date_header= link_to "Release Date", movies_path(:sort=>'release_date', :params[:ratings]=>params[:ratings])
```

Ultimately I want the URL like "/moves/?sort=release_date&Ratings[PG]=1&Ratings[G]=1" where I am spitting out the ratings params back to the page as part of the URL. Or how to I pass the ratings params in any part of page where the existing controller code will read it.

Existing controller code access ratings from checkbox:

```
params[:ratings]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since movies_path accepts hash as parameter, you can tailor params and then generate the URL with movies_path(params). Generally, you may need to remove "controller" and "action" from params.